# Выбор рандомного победителя из массива JS с разным процентом победы

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Имеется многомерный массив. В котором содержаться пользователи. Так же в этот массив заношу процент их победы, он зависит от ставки, процент сам я уже просчитываю.
Пример массива:

```
users.push([1, 60]);
users.push([2, 40]);
```

В массиве 1-ое число - это ID пользователя. Второй процент его победы.
Пользователей может быть неограниченное количество, при каждом новом пользователе процент пересчитывается и через определенное время, пользователи больше не могут начинать игру.
В этот момент нужно просчитать кто победил.
Никак не могу придумать, как по итогу выбирать пользователя.
Может кто-нибудь подобное делал, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод рулетки, применяемый в генетических алгоритмах.

Выбирайте случайное число от 0 до суммы по процентам (пусть будет 100%).
Начинайте перебирать элементы массива с начала суммируя итоговый процент пока не получите значение, превышающее ранее полученное случайное число. Цикл остановится на победителе.

Пример, пусть вероятности 4-х игроков: 10%, 40%, 30%, 20%.

Случайное число 55%.

1-й элемент - 10 (10);

2-й элемент - 50 (10+40);

3-й элемент - 80 (50+30) - победитель.

Comment: Не совсем понятен принцип работы, но звучит правдоподобно

Comment: @MoloF, принцип в том, что чем больше сектор рулетки (доля от общей суммы), тем больше вероятность того, что случайное число попадет в этот сектор.

Comment: Изначально не хотел такой вариант использовать. Поскольку если поменять местами игроков уже совсем результат друго

Comment: @Apelsin2020, при большой выборке (проведении большого количества определения победителей) как раз ничего не изменится, т.е. игрок с заданной вероятностью 20% победит примерно в 20% случаев.